# video letterboxing in premiere pro with the same image as background

Tags: video, premiere

I am creating a slide show in premiere pro and the slideshow contains few portrait images and few box images. which give a black letterbox. I want the letterbox to show the same image blurred as background.

example:

[image: example]

or this youtube video: (I dont want to add links)

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Qm07MUkgiA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the picture into a second video track. Then, zoom in the picture on the lower track (i.e. increase it's size in the effect settings panel). Then, apply a gaussian blur from the effects panel and raise the blur factor in the effect settings panel until you are satisfied with the result.

If you need more detailed instructions, please provide some additional info on how you set up your project in Premiere Pro, what you have tried to achieve this and why it didn't work.